How to show nested hierarchy in UI
I am working on this screen where we have multiple quotes, inside of which there are different numbers that can be assigned to a quote. So for eg. in the image attached, lines John & cicily are within Quote 1. How can we better display visually that John mayer and Cicily Mayer are oart of Quote 1? The top part "Custom quote is a header.


The solution is using tabs for each item:


This would been my ideal solution but the client don't use patterns like these. Top custom quote part is a separate header pattern.
